# How can you draw custom ViewGroup in Android (API Level 23+) and outside of that ViewGroup should be still accessible?

Tags: android, accessibility, drawing, android-viewgroup

I am working on a project where I need to do mainly 4 stuff:

1. Get screen source
2. Find out on which button/text/image user has clicked
3. Draw the red rectangle around that object.
4. Repeat

So, what I have achievid so far.

1. to get the screen source, I am using `AccessibilityService` where I override `onAccessibilityEvent`
2. from `onAccessibilityEvent` I get the information about the bounds where to draw. (Like in Rect class, `top`, `left`, `bottom`, `right`)
3. I have created custom view which extends `ViewGroup`
4. I have overloaded `onMeasure`, `onDraw` methods.

I successfully draw red Rects around the button/text/image, but unfortunately, I am not able to access any other stuff on the screen (i.e the screen gets overloaded by my view and I can't click anymore on the screen)

I have tried:

1. making the custom view's height and width so small that I thought it wouldn't overload the whole screen. The idea actually **worked**, *but* it wasn't drawing anymore where I wanted.

Here is my `AccessibilityService`'s meta-data (xml config)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:description="@string/app_name"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
    android:packageNames="XX XXX" <!-- I've removed these for some purposes -->
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackAllMask"
    android:canRequestFilterKeyEvents="true"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagIncludeNotImportantViews|flagRequestTouchExplorationMode|flagReportViewIds"
    android:notificationTimeout="100"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    android:canRequestTouchExplorationMode="true"
    android:canPerformGestures="true"
    android:canTakeScreenshot="true">

</accessibility-service>
```

This is how I *technically* draw something on screen:

```
val drw = DrawingView(this)
val params = WindowManager.LayoutParams()
params.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH
params.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_ACCESSIBILITY_OVERLAY
params.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
val wm = getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
wm.addView(drw, params)
```

I insert the image as well:
[image: Pixel phone red box on nine]

After drawing this red box (Rectangle) the whole screen is **inaccessible**.

I want to:
When I draw the red rectangle, I want other buttons to be accessible as well, because to remove the current red rectangle and draw a new one...

Imagine that this app is something similar to [TalkBack](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6283677?hl=en) (Android's integrated accessibility service)

Answer (score 1):

It does look like you're trying to call the [`setAccessibilityFocusAppearance`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService#setAccessibilityFocusAppearance(int,%20int)), which has been added in Android S - so that might not be all that helpful.

Looking at the [AccessibilityService codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/developing-android-a11y-service#3), they add their view without overriding the layout params `type` field:

```
       // Create an overlay and display the action bar
       WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
       mLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
       WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
       lp.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_ACCESSIBILITY_OVERLAY;
       lp.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
       lp.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE; // <--- here
       lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
       lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
       lp.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
       LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
       inflater.inflate(R.layout.action_bar, mLayout);
       wm.addView(mLayout, lp);
```

So I would recommend you try changing

```
    params.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH
```

to the following:

```
   params.flags = params.flags or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
```